# xtable: extend table to both columns

Tags: positioning, knitr, sweave, xtable

Using the `xtable` package, is it possible to give some option to `xtable` function to generate a tex file which will contain following:

````
```
\begin{table*}
...
\end{table*}
```
````

Comment: do you want something like `print(xtable(data.frame(3)), floating.environment = "table*")` ? If not, please give more details and a minimal example.

Comment: Was struggling with this yesterday, and I was surprised now seeing your answer. Not believing such simple solution, I went through the xtable documentation again and realised "Possible values include "table", "table*", and other floating environments defined in LaTeX packages". Many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @scottkosty btw, could you please put this in the answer section just in case that somebody else need it. of course, I'll vote it up. thanks once more!

Comment: done. Glad it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `floating.environment` option while reading the following documentation:

```
library(xtable)
?print.xtable
```

For example:

```
print(xtable(data.frame(3)), floating.environment = "table*")
```

Note that this is an option to `print.xtable`, not to `xtable` directly. Another option that is related is `tabular.environment`.